# What does the line behind zoning symbolize?

Tags: simcity-2013

When I go to zone some land I have a box that hugs the road symbolizing the buildings. However, there is also a depth line drawn at what I would assume is the possible largest building size. The thing is I can still zone regardless of if that line is red or green. Will this zone still flourish if I place it when the line is red?

Comment: any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: Sadly I am at work at the moment and finding a screenshot that specific may be tough haha. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I suspect it is a line detailing the maximum growth but won't be sure until I see what you're talking about. In these instances, the zone does require a minimum amount of space to create a building at all, so leaving too little space will waste the zone, but it is possible to create plots that only have enough space for a particular density of construction and in those cases you will end up with a zone with a small house in it, that will never grow larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a line that appears a short distance away from the road while zoning.  That line shows you the distance a building will require in order to develop a lot at that point.  If there is insufficient room, the lot will not develop.

Think of it in terms of street widths.  Streets are 1 street wide.  Avenues are 2 streets wide.  Low density lots are 2 streets long.  Medium and high density lots are 4 streets long.

If you zone where two streets meet forming an acute angle, development will not occur until the point where the streets are 2 street widths apart.

---

When zoning against a medium density street (or higher), the helper line will be bright, dim, or red.  Bright indicates medium and high density buildings have enough room.  Dim indicates low density buildings have enough room (medium and high will not develop).  Red means that no buildings will develop.

Comment: So why am I even allowed to zone it if the game knows it won't develop?

Comment: Zoning is free!  Extra zoning doesn't hurt the city in any way.  Also - if the obstacle is later removed, a lot will develop.

Comment: This pretty much - there is no cost in zoning or dezoning, the game doesn't tell you where to put your roads, you have to make that choice for yourself. If you get it wrong - nothing will develop, but at least you were allowed to get it wrong!

Comment: Also, I wonder if beautification is dependent on zoning. I had a lot with acute angle zoned commercial, and once the building upgraded in density and wealth, I had a small row of trees with benches or somesuch show up there. Would they shop up if it would not have been zoned?